# How to remove Quick links, news with json

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, json

I would like to remove default team site components such as: Quick links and news. So far I have been using Site design JSON schema to change navigation(remove, add new) on the left side.

Can this be done with a script and JSON schema ?  Maybe it can be done in some other way e.g. with power shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PnP PowerShell to Add Link to Quick Launch:**

```
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Contoso" -Url "http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso/" -Location "QuickLaunch"
```

**PnP PowerShell to Remove Link to Quick Launch:**

```
Remove-PnPNavigationNode -Title Recent -Location QuickLaunch
```

**Here is the PnP PowerShell script to add link to Quick Launch:**

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/us"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
     
    #Add a Link to Quick Launch Navigation
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Support Center" -Url "http://support.crescent.com" -Location "QuickLaunch"
 
    #Get the Navigation node "Support Center"
    $ParentID = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location QuickLaunch | Where {$_.Title -eq "Support Center"}  | Select -ExpandProperty ID
    #Add a link under "Support Center
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Application Support" -Url "http://support.crescent.com/apps" -Location "QuickLaunch" -Parent $ParentID
  
    Write-host "Quick Launch Links Added Successfully!" -f Green
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

More information, please refer to the following articles:

- **[Add-PnPNavigationNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps)**
- **[Remove-PnPNavigationNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps)**

========================== **Updated Answer** =========================

**Please run the following PnP PowerShell script:**

```
#Connect to Site
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Echo"
$Cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

#Retrieve all web parts used in modern site pages.
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx"
$WebParts = $page.Controls

# if there are more than one webparts  
foreach($webpart in $webparts){  
       Write-Host "Title: " $webpart.Title 
       Write-Host "WebPart Id:  " $webpart.InstanceId    
}
```

[image]

**Then, please run the following command to remove webpart.**

```
#Remove webpart 
Remove-PnPClientSideComponent -Page $page -InstanceId 418ba70b-4cf7-410a-a5fd-ea38386915ac
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not talking about navigation. I mean the parts of the site that are there when you enter Home. These are two default Web Part Quick links and news. I tried to use this script but after login I get 403 code .https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/05/sharepoint-online-delete-web-part-from-page-using-powershell.html

Comment: Hi, Jelon3k. Thanks for your reply. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It does what it needs to do

```
try {​​​​​​​​
```

Connect-PnPOnline-Urlhttps://yourname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite
$page=Get-PnPClientSidePage-Identity"Home.aspx"
#Retrieve webparts from modern page
$webParts=$page.Controls
foreach($webpartin$webparts) {​​​​​​​​
Write- Host "WebPart Id "
$webpart.InstanceId
Write- Host "Title "
$webpart.Title
}​​​​​​​​
Remove-PnPClientSideComponent-Page$page-InstanceId Your Id
}​​​​​​​​ catch {​​​​​​​​
Write- Host - ForegroundColor Red 'Error ',':'
$Error[0].ToString();
sleep10
}​​​​​​​​